# How to make tkinter::pack() place label on top left corner in below program?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using pack() to align label and buttons on tkinter.The following code:

```
from tkinter import *
wind=Tk()
wind.geometry('450x450')
l1=Label(wind,text='Did you mean:')
l1.pack(side=LEFT)
b1=Button(wind,text='Button1',width=450)
b1.pack()
b2=Button(wind,text='Button2',width=450)
b2.pack()
wind.mainloop()
```

gives output:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a14P.png)

I tried removing the `side=LEFT` from `l1.pack(side=LEFT)` it gives: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIb3k.png).

For me expected output is label l1 on top left corner and the buttons stacked below it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`pack` works with a box model, aligning widgets along one side of the empty space in a container. Thus, to put something along the top, you need to use `side="top"` (or `side=TOP` if you prefer using a named constant), and it needs to come before other widgets.

In your specific case, to get the widget aligned at the top, you would do the following:

```
l1.pack(side=TOP)
```

By default this will center the widget along the top edge. If you also want the label aligned to the left, you would use the `anchor` option, which takes points of a compass ("n", "s", "e", "w", "nw", etc).

Thus, to place the widget at the top, and anchor it to the top-left corner you would do something like this:

```
l1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as I wanted it to. I visited many websites on tkinter, but none of them had anything about anchor. I know something like it exists only after you told about it.

Comment: @NikithClan: you don't have to search the internet. It's mentioned right in the tkinter help text (eg: `import tkinter; print(help(tkinter))`).