# How do I put tk button on the top RIGHT

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I can't put the button on the top right

The code on `TOP RIGHT` is an err

```
photo = PhotoImage(file = "cross-mark (Custom).png")
Button(root, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo).pack(side = TOP RIGHT)
```

[The code err photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfxFa.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make tkinter::pack() place label on top left corner in below program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016467/how-to-make-tkinterpack-place-label-on-top-left-corner-in-below-program)

Answer (score 0):

`side` just accept one of the four directions available, in your case if you want it to align to the top right you should also include the `anchor` flag, which accept the points of a compass, in your case if you should try

```
Button(root, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo).pack(side = TOP, anchor = NE)
```